# Why WPF controls not same scroll bar styles?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, styles, scrollbar

I have a WPF WebBrowser control beside a WPF TreeView control. Both have default styles with default properties. I have not changed anything except placing them on my WPF window. If you view the screen shot below you can see the two controls have two different scroll bars. I have no idea why this is happening.

Is there a way to make one control's scroll bar look like the other, or just default them both to windows styles?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment:

> Is there a way to keep that theme in my resources (my ribbon control uses it) and just remove the scroll bar theme from that tree view control? – Landin Martens Jun 23 at 19:49

Yes.

## Option 1

You can override the default style for a control like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
  ...
</Style>
```

This will change the styling for every TreeView control (assuming the style is defined in your App.xaml dictionary). If you only want to override the style for a few controls, you can name it:

```
<Style x:Key="XTreeViewStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
  ...
</Style>
```

And the set the style explicitly for those controls (`<TreeView Style="{StaticResource XTreeViewStyle}"/>`). Or, you can create the style within a specific context, such as a Grid (thus affecting only those controls within the Grid):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

It is my guess that the style which is overriding your scrollbars is not targeting TreeViews specifically... it is probably targeting a control that TreeView inherits from. So, look for a default style which targets TreeView, ItemsControl, Control, FrameworkElement or UIElement. When you find it, you can either give it a name, or move the style into a more limited context.

For example, your styles are probably set up something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
  ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon}">
  <Style.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ItemsControl>
        ...
      </ItemsControl>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Style.Template>
</Style>
```

To have the ItemsControl style only affect the Ribbon, you could move the ItemsControl style into the Ribbon's template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon}">
  <Style.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
          ...
        </Style>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <ItemsControl>
        ...
      </ItemsControl>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Style.Template>
</Style>
```

The exact approach, however, is going to depend on how exactly your styles are setup, and this may be much more complicated then I have suggested. For example, if you have several different styles which all need to use that ItemsControl style, you might use naming and inheritance like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}"
       x:Key="XItemsControlStyle">
  ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon}">
  <Style.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource XItemsControlStyle}">
          ...
        </Style>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <ItemsControl>
        ...
      </ItemsControl>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Style.Template>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonItem}">
  <Style.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource XItemsControlStyle}">
          ...
        </Style>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <ItemsControl>
        ...
      </ItemsControl>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Style.Template>
</Style>
```

## Option 2

Set the style for the TreeView explicitly. This will mean finidng the original style for the TreeView (or at least the one you want to use), giving it a name and then setting explicitly on the TreeView you want to style. (See Option 2 for how to do that)

I believe that these links will provide you with default styles:

- [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728671.aspx)
- [ScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx)
- [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a custom theme in your application resources. The `WebBrowser` doesn't use the style from the theme, because it's not a WPF control, it's just a wrapper for a Win32 control. So you can't make the WebBrowser scroll bar look like the one on the left. If you want to get rid of the custom style, you should remove it from your resources.

Comment: Is there a way to keep that theme in my resources (my ribbon control uses it) and just remove the scroll bar theme from that tree view control?

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowser` is just a wrapper around native component and it's really hard to deal with that in WPF. I had a lot of pain with it in my projects.

So, it can be good idea to try [Chromium for WPF](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex. It is much more flexible.

Comment: That project is to big in size, my current application is still under 3MB but that is just to big.